# HTML5 / JavaScript / JQuery - Best way to get form associated with input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Before HTML5, I used to be able to easily find the form associated with an input using jQuery, because all inputs were contained within the form element.

For example, with jQuery I would do something like:

```
jQuery('.info-container input').closest('form')
```

I still would like to use jQuery because I use some features that are easier to implement in jQuery.  But, with HTML5, inputs can be outside of the form element.  For example the following can be anywhere in the HTML but still part of the form:

```
<input name='city' form='address_form'>
```

Is there any easy way in jQuery to get the form associated with a given input/button/select ?

Comment: `$('#'+$('input').attr('form'))`

Comment: @StackSlave That will return a string, not the element.

Comment: why not get the value using id? and anything about it.then you might use FormData. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `form` property to get the associated form.

```
$($('input[name=city]').prop('form'))
```

I believe this will work whether the input is inside a form or uses the `form` attribute to connect with a form.

Comment: That would be great. I'll try it out later today.

Answer (score 0):

How about just get list using this.

```
var inputs = $(document).find('input[form="address_form"]');
```

then you can find what input you want within form "address_form" using their name. But if you just need one element, just like this

```
var inputs = $(document).find('input[form="address_form"][name="city"]');
```

Comment: I think the point is that the application doesn't know which form the input is associated with, it needs to determine it dynamically.

Comment: This would come up in an event handler that's assigned or delegated to multiple inputs, and needs to get the form associated with `$(this)`.

Comment: This jQuery("form#myform input").css("color","red") didn't find inputs outside of the form HTML element, but I am using an old version of jQuery I think.  1.12